# Swal is not defined using laravel livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, sweetalert

I am using laravel livewire component and I want to provide feedback to users with sweetalerts (realrashid/sweet-alert) using Swal.

I am getting this issue in console:
`Swal is not defined`

This is my component class:

```
 $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('swal', [
            'title' => __('Meal created successfully.'),
            'timer'=> 3000,
            'icon'=> 'success',
            'toast'=> true,
            'position'=> 'top-right'
        ]);
```

and this is its view:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('swal', function (e) {
            Swal.fire(e.detail)
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

This is main blade where I have stack of scripts:

```
<livewire:scripts/>
@include('sweetalert::alert')
@stack('scripts')
```

I guess the order is right...

Also, I have followed realrashid docs for installation of the sweetalerts and I have installed sweetalert2 with npm.

I have done this before but I am missing something now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the included view look like? How do you expose the Swal package in your script?

Comment: @Qirel sorry don't understand. You want to see components view or the view that loads component? :D

Comment: How exactly have you installed Swal? Which package in NPM? Then, what did you do after installing it? What made you put `@include('sweetalert::alert')` in your layout?

Comment: @Qirel oh okay, so I was using realrashid/sweet-alert package and that is why I have that include but later on I also installed `npm i sweetalert2` and then have also tried to put `.extract({'sweetalert2})` in .mix but didn't help. Really tried everything I could find :D I guess I am missing something but I don't see what.